# Parse Date from String: hidden runes

Tags: date, go

I'm parsing dates directly from an HTML file and attempting to convert them to date. However, doing so always reflects in an error; the strangest part is that I'm able to parse if I paste the string directly.

```
layout := "02-01-2006 15:04:05"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, *date)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println( err)
}
```

Yields:

```
parsing time "12-06-2021   00:00:31" as "02-01-2006 15:04:05": cannot parse "  00:00:31" as "15"
```

If however, I try to parse directly from string, it works:

```
layout := "02-01-2006 15:04:05"
date := "12-06-2021   00:00:31"
t, err := time.Parse(layout, date)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println( err)
}
```

Works just fine. I tried removing whitespace in every possible manner, and the problem persists:

```
date2 := *date
date2 = strings.TrimSpace(date2)
date2 = strings.TrimRight(date2, "\r\n")
date2 = strings.TrimRight(date2, "\n")

space := regexp.MustCompile(`\s+`)
date2 = space.ReplaceAllString(date2, "")
date2 = strings.ReplaceAll(date2, " ", "")
date2 = strings.ReplaceAll(date2, "\r", "")
date2 = strings.ReplaceAll(date2, "\n", "")
```

This suggests there are hidden runes. Finally, I resorted to printing the actual runes in both the original string (from pointer) and my pasted version, and this is what I get.

Original string:

```
0: U+0031 '1'
1: U+0033 '3'
2: U+002D '-'
3: U+0030 '0'
4: U+0037 '7'
5: U+002D '-'
6: U+0032 '2'
7: U+0030 '0'
8: U+0032 '2'
9: U+0031 '1'
10: U+00A0
12: U+0031 '1'
13: U+0030 '0'
14: U+003A ':'
15: U+0030 '0'
16: U+0030 '0'
17: U+003A ':'
18: U+0030 '0'
19: U+0030 '0'
```

Hand-pasted string:

```
0: U+0031 '1'
1: U+0032 '2'
2: U+002D '-'
3: U+0030 '0'
4: U+0036 '6'
5: U+002D '-'
6: U+0032 '2'
7: U+0030 '0'
8: U+0032 '2'
9: U+0031 '1'
10: U+0020 ' '
11: U+0030 '0'
12: U+0030 '0'
13: U+003A ':'
14: U+0030 '0'
15: U+0030 '0'
16: U+003A ':'
17: U+0033 '3'
18: U+0032 '2'
```

Immediately we can spot the problem: there is an additional rune in position 11, but for some reason, it is now shown; how come? what is it? and how to remove it?

Comment: `fmt.Printf("%q", *date)` is a good way to identify weird things in strings. Here you've got an non-breaking-space (unicode 0xa0), whereas the format string contains a regular space.

Comment: Thank you for your help! For future reference, here is the solution:
`*date = strings.Replace(*date, "\u00a0", "", -1)`
Note: ReplaceAll does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U+00A0 is the non-breaking space character. It's often used in datetimes formatted for human use to ensure the datetime won't be wrapped by the displaying program.

You might want to just try replacing any `\uA0` characters with a regular space first.

As for why regexps won't do anything, it's not matched by your `\s` regexp since the docs say it's strictly

```
\s             whitespace (== [\t\n\f\r ])
```

Comment: Thank you @AKX, this was indeed the solution. For future reference, note that ReplaceAll will not work, instead, use:
`*date = strings.Replace(*date, "\u00a0", "", -1)`